# how to declare resources in wpf using prism?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

Earlier I was working with WPF whenever I've to declare resources, I declare in App.xaml and call them in the entire project where I need them but now I'm Using Prism Technology, and I don't know where to declare resources and how to call them.

Comment: What error do you get when you declare resources in app.xaml? What makes you believe that you cannot do that when using the Prism framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your resources the same way prior to using PRISM. It can be declared in any xaml file or control e.g. App.xaml, MainWindow.xaml, UserControl.xaml, Grid, TextBox etc. The only difference it makes is on the scope of the resource:

For **Global** accessibility in all of the Windows and User Controls of the Project, you can have your resource in the App.xaml file

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="LargeFontSize">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

For accessibility at a Window level, you can have your resource in your xaml file for Window

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="LargeFontSize">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

You could even have it at a Control level, for example

```
<DockPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="LargeFontSize">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28"/>
    </Style>
</DockPanel.Resources>
```

You can call it by:

```
<Label Content="Name" Style="{StaticResource LargeFontSize}" />
```